# Encobrindo endereço de URL no href

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso encobrir o endereço original de uma *url* seguindo o exemplo desta *url* que segue os parâmetros da *url* do servidor que eu uso `http://thumb.servidor.direto.com.br/15574899.mp4` para ficar desta forma no `href="/linkdireto/15574899.mp4` sendo que o link direto e de um servidor de hospedagem e não tenho acesso a ele para poder criar um `.htacess` e qualquer outro tipo de alteração no servidor uma vez que eu envio arquivo e ele gera uma `URL` para copiar.

Há possibilidade de fazer isso com *php* ou no `htacess` no meu site ?

Comment: pode fazer isso com httaccess no seu servidor, independente do arquivo estar em outro server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem, crie um script php com o nome que quiser e cole nele o código abaixo substituindo URL pela url de destino (do arquivo)
Vou arrumar a exibição do código assim que chegar em casa

```php
<?php
 #Preencha esta variável com a URL de destino
 $redirect = "http://URL";
 
 header("location:$redirect");

?>
```

Exemplo:

```php
<?php
 #Preencha esta variável com a URL de destino
 $redirect = "http://servidor/arquivos/media/loading.mp4";
 
 
 header("location:$redirect");
?>
```

Comment: No caso seria eu criar um link tipo assim no href="link.php?id=15574899" disso fazer este valor se aplicado ao $redirect = "http://thumb.servidor.direto.com.br/$_GET["id"].mp4"; fazendo assim abrir na header ?

Comment: Já obtive aqui graças a sua ajuda fazer o que eu queria grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Se fizer isso com a intenção de esconder do usuário, estará fazendo errado. Ao invés escreva o conteúdo do request no corpo da resposta.

Comment: Uma boa dica se quiser esconder e usar post por meio de um formulário hidden